# Repeat typewriter text animation when the text changes

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-animations

In my React component I have a text that changes every 4 seconds:

```
<div className="fullscreen-text">
   <p>{loadingPhrases[phraseIndex]}</p>
</div>
```

React code:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setPhraseIndex(Math.floor(Math.random() * 9));

    }, 4000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);
```

I want this text to appear with the typewriter effect every time it changes. I use such a css:

```
 .fullscreen-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    animation: typewriter 5s steps(60) forwards;
  }

  @keyframes typewriter {
    from {
      width: 0;
    }
    to {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
```

But with this code, the typewriter effect is only applied at the beginning. How do make the text 'printed' every time it changes?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you set your `animation-fill-mode` to `forwards` which causes the target element to retain the style values that is set by the last keyframe.
The solution is change it to infinite.

Furthermore, you set the `animation-duration` to `5s` whereas the text changes every 4s, this leads to the text visibly changing before the animation restarts.

I also created a backwards printer animation because of slight delays between react's `setInterval` and CSS's animation-duration, this animation hides the text whenever it is changed in order to avoid such visual inconsistencies.

```css
.fullscreen-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: typewriter 7s steps(60) infinite; // Full animation duration
}

// New animation
@keyframes typewriter {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
  }
  75% {
    width: 100%;
  }
  95% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
const [phraseIndex, setPhraseIndex] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setPhraseIndex(Math.floor(Math.random() * 9));

    }, 7000); // Full animation duration
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);
```

EDIT: I suggest changing the animation width unit to `ch` as in `50% {width: 50ch;}` if your animated text has a somewhat fixed length, this creates a real typewriter effect, I do not recommend it if your phrases vary in length.